# Vertical align middle for responsive top navigation without fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to center the text in my top navigation below vertically.
I tried to give my *.header* a *height:3em;* and use *vertical-align:middle;* but then my responsive fold-out menu can't handle the fixed height. The menu doesnt appear anymore because the height is fixed now.
I also tried with .parent *padding:50% 0;* and .child *margin:0 auto;* but I don't get the trick.
I also tried to use *line-height:40px* and it looks ok - but my burger-menu-icon won't center this way.
My burger-menu-icon also has problems when using % and translate, i can center it this way - but with fold-out menu it's also moving to the 50% and that's not wanted. Changing to fixed/absolute will crash the % and translate...

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(1.3em + 1vw)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

/* header */

.header {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  background: #ffb347;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */ 
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo:hover {
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0.9em 0.4em;
  user-select: none;
  background: blue; 
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 40px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 15px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -15px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 100%;

}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 920px) {
  .header {
    position: relative;
  }
  .header li {
    float: left;   
  }
  .header li a {
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">LOREM <b>IPSUM</b></a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#work"> <b>Lorem</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><b>Ipsum</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#careers"><b>Dolor</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><b>Sit</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

Start it in Full-Page!

Comment: Did you try setting `margin` in `%` like this `.header .menu { margin-top: 1%;}`

Comment: It actually moves down, but it's not really centered.

Comment: Then use `display:flex` and `align-item: center` I added my ans below

Comment: first rule of centring: Never use float

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of another idea to create a responsive menu.  How would you design that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css `transform` `transform: translateY(10%);` check snippet.

```css
html {
  font-size: calc(1.3em + 1vw)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}


/* header */

.header {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  background: #ffb347;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header .logo:hover {}


/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(19%);
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.9em 0.4em;
  user-select: none;
  background: blue;
  transform: translateY(10%);
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 40px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 15px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -15px;
}


/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .header .menu {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 920px) {
  .header {
    position: relative;
  }
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {}
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">LOREM <b>IPSUM</b></a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#work"> <b>Lorem</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about"><b>Ipsum</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers"><b>Dolor</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><b>Sit</b></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: The links in the desktop version are still not centered. And the menu button is not really centered with tansform 10%, as I wrote above

Comment: check now i have added transform to menu as well.

Comment: Now there is a space between the logo and links when the menu is opened. It's also there for scrolling, probably through a fixed height.

Comment: you can use media query to reduce that space check updated answer.

Comment: That's not exactly in the middle but i can live with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This causes my foldout menu to no longer work.

Comment: Use media query for mobile(update my answer)

Comment: My menu opens on the right side then, not on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below CSS :

```
.header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Comment: On the desktop with a small browser it looks ok, on the smartphone not really in the middle.